# Get normalized coordinates for selected rectangle size (crop rectangle from area)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

First of all, see the Area explanation:[Area explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwRuP.png)

I'm not really good at math, but this problem seems very easy and straightforward. However, I can't figure out what calculations I need to do to get the final answer.

So. We have area A, which is a unit plane. We also have area B, which has dimensions of 896x615 pixels.
Problem: we need to find the coordinates of points $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$. Or in other words, we need to crop area C from area B which will be 340x400 pixels. (area C can be selected at any points of area B).

My attempts.
Initially, we only know the exact size of area B (896x615 pixels) and what ratio this is to the whole area: 0.8759765625.
So, to find the widths, we need to calculate:
$$\frac{896}{0.8759765}=\frac{x_{1}}{1}\rightarrow x_{1}=\frac{896}{0.8759765}=1022.858489925243$$

$$\frac{615}{0.6015625}=\frac{x_{2}}{1}\rightarrow x_{2}=\frac{615}{0.6015625}=1022.337662337662$$

Thus, $x_{1}\neq x_{2}$. Is this error in calculations?

So, area A is a 1022x1022 pixels grid, right?

But how to get right now coordinates for points $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$ (in normalized value (such as 0.342412, 0.484712, etc.) I don't know. I have read about affine transformation, but I don't know how to use it in this case. Can you explain which calculations I should do for result? I'n my opinion there must be some sort of parameterized expression in which we can substitute all the original data.